# Can't hit Web API from php

Tags: php, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to call this

```
    [Route("CreateHL7TestFile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateHL7TestFile([FromBody] JObject data)
    {
     // Code here
     }
```

from a php function using cUrl.  When I try and call the API without passing any data it works fine.  It's when I try and add the '$data' that I cannot hit the API.  When I call the API with data from Postman it also works fine.  So I'm assuming my error is on the php side?

My php function looks like this.

```
  public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
  {         
   $data = array("value1" => "some value");

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('test1' => 'value1', 'test2' => 'value2')));

 $result = curl_exec($ch);

 print_r($result);
 curl_close($ch);
```

}

```
http://localhost:50999/api/ParticipantAPI/CreateHL7TestFile
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Can you show what you're sending on postman? if it's a body, it has to be key value

Comment: I actually have an array that I'm planning on passing but I just wanted to get a single value to work first.  My value is that I'm passing in from Postman is just 
{
 "HL7":"TEST"
}

Even when I create the php array with

     $dat = array("HL7" => "TEST");     

I still can't hit it.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to accept the call on the Web API side?

Comment: Check my answer friend, see if it helps, the api looks fine, depending if you are expecting of a certain type or structure.

Comment: @brachen33 Show the URL being called and show the acion's controller as well in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem

Comment: Also, make sure what type of Content-type are you sending in the postman. .NET is very picky when it comes to receiving data

Comment: I added the URL I'm calling for the API, and updated the current php function that is hitting the API, just with no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper model on the asp.net-core server to bind incoming data

```
public class MyData {
    public string value1 { get; set;}
}
```

And update action accordingly

```
[Route("CreateHL7TestFile")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateHL7TestFile([FromBody] MyData data) {
    // Code here
}
```

Referencing the following article [POSTing JSON Data With PHP cURL](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

Try the following on the PHP side

```
$data = array("value1" => "some value");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

For your real requests refactor the expected data model accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
   {         
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('test1' => 'value1', 'test2' => 'value2')));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);

     print_r($result);
     curl_close($ch); 
}
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

If you want to send json, then I think you'll have to set the header, something like:

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
   {         
     $dat = array("TEST1","TEST2");     
     $data = json_encode($dat);        
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);

     print_r($result);
     curl_close($ch);     
}
```

Comment: Still nothing.  My $result just returns as true but it isn't hitting it because it isn't hitting the breakpoints in the API.

Comment: which of these have you tried? first one should work. Add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); to my first example